Is there evidence to support the idea that Israel liked some degree of violence committed by Hamas?
According to an article by BBC

In 2019, Mr Netanyahu told colleagues in his ruling Likud party: "Anyone who wants to thwart the establishment of a Palestinian state has to support bolstering Hamas and transferring money to Hamas… This is part of our strategy - to isolate the Palestinians in Gaza from the Palestinians in the West Bank."

One might speculate as well that the acts of violence by Hamas gave Israel pretext for their militarism and for further suppression of Palestinians, especially if Israel considered the military power of Hamas fairly weak. But is there any evidence supporting this idea?

There are ... in the quote. The context might be interesting there. Also the title of this question is a bit different from the body, maybe both can be made to match more closely. Finally, this question might have been asked before in one form or another. Was a search for that performed?

In the case of Netanyahu, there certainly seems to be some evidence, which you provided. Now, the extent to which Netanyahu's position represented that of his party, Likud, and the extent to which Likud's position represented that of the coalition government—e.g. Likud had about 30% of the votes in 2020, and of course their voters might support some of their policies and dislike others—and the extent to which the coalition government's position represented that of most Israelis, could be quite a different matter.

The quote can be interpreted many ways. One is the idea that it supports violence. Another is that he's calling Hamas a poison to the Palestinian cause, and that Israel's strategy is to keep Palestinian's divided and bickering rather than presenting a united force.

@DavidS - It's definitely implying that Netanyahu wanted Hamas to be in charge in Gaza to divide it from Fatah in the West Bank. One could reasonably infer thereby that, at the very least, he was willing to accept some foreseeable degree of violence by Hamas against Israelis as the inevitable price of that goal. Going from that to the idea that he wanted the violence specifically is bit more of a stretch, but not at all out of the question in my view. But "Israel" as an entity is quite a bit bigger than Netanyahu, which I think is where the premise potentially overreaches.

Afaik Netanyahu intentionally did not harm Hamas much more, because he has seen in them an opponent of the Fatah. Divide et impera. After 7.10, he must attack, because the society wanted a bloody revenge. In this sense, he probably did not want it, he wanted to harm the Palestinians by dividing them and not by a costly and dangerous war (resulting his resignation at the end).

Upvoted.  However, not sure how much hard evidence can be expected to surface.  Yes, Hamas seems to have been used as a foil to Fatah.  But encouraging significant violence?  Yes, govts occasionally employ "agents provocateurs" at times.  But competent govts would also go to extraordinary lengths to cover their tracks when doing so (off the record meetings, without minutes or recording, few participants).  So expecting clear indications of Bibi doing/not doing this is unrealistic, leaving everyone to pursue their own prejudices:  "Of course he did!" / "No, he would never do that!"

For decades, the Israelis strategy was divide and conquer: 48 Palestinians, occupied Palestinians, and Palestinian refugees. From the 1970's the PLO/Fatah was a uniting force, hence the Israelis saw the Muslim Brotherhood/Hamas as a counterbalancing force. They certainly nurtured the Islamists in the early decades. Nowadays, Hamas serves as their alibi, their eternal excuse for usurping more Palestinian land.

@GaslightDeceiveSubvert: presumably they'd prefer ETIM-level of alibi though.

no decent politician will say, even privately, that killing or harming his constituents is in any way welcome, that's just bad politics.

@dandavis: meh, you didn't read Putin then. Of course, he puts like "don't die of alcoholism, die conquering Ukraine".

"Israel" is not a single individual but a nation of nearly 10M. Some (e.g. Netanyahu) may "like" it while others don't.

The question should be clear if it is asking about Netanyahu's opinion, or otherwise what it means for Israel (a country) to like something. If the question is just about Netanyahu's opinion, the question should also be clarified to explain what it is seeking beyond the evidence included in the question, which shows Netanyahu's opinion as of 2019.

Before asking for evidence the political belief is true ask for evidence it exists. What evidence is there that Netanyahu actually said that?

@Schmerel What would constitute "evidence"? An audio or video recording of him saying it?

Someone  who was known to have  been there claiming  Netanyahu actually said that would be evidence. An anti-Israeli media venue  quoting no actual source is not anymore evidence than an anonymous online claim. Anyone can make that up

It's quite customary to anthropomorphize states. We talk for example about what "America's strategy is" or what "Russia's ambitions are". That does not cause ambiguity.  For good reasons, we assume there is overlap between what the state wants and what the long-term leader of that state wants. Putin in case of Russia and Netanyahu in the case of Israel.

@GaslightDeceiveSubvert You make a good point. However this Q was on its way to being closed before I edited the headline as these nuances are easy to miss (or deliberately overlooked).

"Israel" would be/is the very recipient of that violence... So to argue that "Israel", as a collective whole, likes some degree of violence against itself, is asinine.
Also the reaction is far from unanimous appraisal and support for the Israel-Hamas war.

By 22 December 2023, 67% of Israelis supported a ceasefire in exchange for the return of hostages held by Hamas.

And it's not that the government has total support of the population either:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020%E2%80%932021_protests_against_Benjamin_Netanyahu
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Israeli_judicial_reform_protests
So the collectivization of Israel liking any of that is pretty far out there.
With regards to whether hardliners, opponents of a two-state-solution and Netanyahu in particular see that as advantages.
Well apparently he did make that quote or something along the lines of that, though apparently the rational was rather that this would be mutually beneficial in preventing a two-state-solution, that the money might appease them (largely humanitarian support that might free hamas money elsewhere) or at the very least that Hamas in Gaza wouldn't have the means or the numbers to be an effective threat. So best case scenario they would be an extremist organization by rhetoric that could be presented as reason why there are no negotiations, but also not a real threat.
And that sounds somewhat more plausible, if Hamas sticks to rhetoric and small scale attacks that couldn't be prevented anyway with or without the money or which would be taken down by the iron dome or military or police that would add to the image, without any significant change to the perception of security in Israel.
Apparently the Israeli security community even had plans of the attack (except for the date), but didn't consider it serious, because they thought Hamas would not be capable of actually doing that and that it's just boasting and making aspirational claims.
While, similar to 9/11 conspiracies, allowing that to happen as a catalyst for revenge is very unlikely. That's essentially high treason right there and no matter how carefully that is planned there will be leaks sooner or later and that's the kind of betrayal of the public that can break a political system or country as a whole. Like allowing thousands of your citizens to be brutally murdered or being captured as hostages, is something no democratic state or it's population could permit as a bargain for war and even if that is only revealed years after the event that would cause massive internal problems.
At best that could be a top-down decision of an undemocratic regime, but even in that case, it's likely going to leak and cause turmoil. So the much more likely explanation is that they really didn't anticipate, that this could be real, meaning a complete failure of the intelligence community. And afterwards either an overcompensation of pretending to show strength to cover up the weakness and the feeling of vulnerability and/or taking advantage of the situation and a shift to more hardliner politics for various reasons using the previous as cover.
So it's not impossible that some hawks would see that as a means to pursue goals they already had for a long time, given a bigger potential for public support, but "to like" violence against oneself is still likely an overstatement and to actively or passively cause or facilitate that could backfire immensely. Like first of all such events highlight your own inaptness to secure the citizens of your country... And especially the taking of hostages has made the counter attacks look less like cathartic revenge and more like unnecessary violence endangering the lives of the hostages.
So no to state your approval of terrorism by a foreign adversary against your own country in any capacity which could be leaked (including even private talk) would render you so much of a traitor that you likely wouldn't be able to ever recover from that. So it's very unlikely to discover any actual evidence of that (without it becoming so public that you could hardly avoid it...).

I don't think the argument is that Israel "likes" to receive violence, assuming it could pick a-la-carte from the political menu. The argument is that they calculate to provoke and accept violence both as the price paid to achieve their own violent political ends, and as a devious manipulation of the situation for their global propaganda purposes.

Hamas started out in the 1970s as an Islamic charity run by Sheikh
Ahmed Yassin. It was part of the wave of political Islam that swept
through the Muslim word in the 1970s and 1980s. Due to its religious
nature, it came in opposition to Yassir Arafat's secular and
nationalist PLO. Thus, it became an asset to Israel which aided
Yassin's charity in these decades.1,2,3,4 While it is of
unclear exactly how much Israel aided Hamas' precursor (all
relevant documents are classified), it most certainly did not crack
down on its activities.
Many decades later, after many international organizations labelled
Hamas a terrorist organization, many Israeli politicians still prefer
Hamas over the more docile Palestinian Authority. This preference makes
sense considering that Israel's long-term goal is retaining occupied
territory and denying the Palestinians statehood. Keeping the
Palestinian Authority weak and Hamas comparatively strong means that
Israeli leaders can continue to repeat that they have "no partner for
peace".5
In 2015 Israeli finance minister Bezalel Smotrich stated that "the
Palestinian Authority is a burden, and Hamas is an asset" and argued
that Hamas is a "terrorist organization, no one will recognize it, no
one will give it status at the [International Criminal Court], no one
will let it put forth a resolution at the U.N. Security
Council."6 According to a leaked cable, in 2007 Israel's
head of military intelligence Amos Yadlin said that "Israel would be
'happy' if Hamas took over Gaza because the IDF could then deal with
Gaza as a hostile state".7 And according to several
journalists, analysts, and others, Benjamin Netanyahu's implicit
strategy is to bolster Hamas at the expense of the Palestinian
Authority.7,8,9,10,11 Israeli major general Gershon Hacohen
stated in 2019: "We need to tell the truth ... Netanyahu’s strategy is
to prevent the option of two states, so he is turning Hamas into his
closest partner. Openly Hamas is an enemy. Covertly, it’s an ally."12

Israel's historical role in the rise of Hamas
Blowback: How Israel Went From Helping Create Hamas to Bombing It
How Israel helped create Hamas
Did Israel create Hamas?
Debunked: Israel has 'no partner for peace'
Before they Vowed to Annihilate Hamas, Israeli Officials Considered it an Asset
Israel ‘happy’ for Hamas to rule Gaza, says cable
A Brief History of the Netanyahu-Hamas Alliance
Why Netanyahu Bolstered Hamas
‘Buying Quiet’: Inside the Israeli Plan That Propped Up Hamas
For years, Netanyahu propped up Hamas. Now it’s blown up in our faces
How Israel helped prop up Hamas for decades


Yes, there is ample circumstantial evidence to suggests that the Israeli-right made it a state policy to fund Islamic terrorists and allow attacks against Israel to:

delegitimise the Palestinian movement,
periodically use violence to cull the Palestinians, and
capture more of their territory.


“In the visible dimension Hamas is an enemy, in the hidden dimension it is an ally.” - IDF Major General Gershon Hacohen


Brigadier General Yitzhak Segev quoted in the “Arab and Jew : wounded spirits in a promised land”:

Politically speaking, Islamic fundamentalists were sometimes regarded as useful to Israel because they had their conflicts with the secular supporters of the PLO. Violence between the groups erupted occasionally on West Bank university campuses, and the Israeli military governor of the Gaza Strip, Brigadier General Yitzhak Segev, once told me how he had financed the Islamic movement as a counterweight to the PLO and the Communists.
“The Israeli Government gave me a budget and the military government gives to the mosques,” he said.


New York Times reported in Casting Blame in the Israel-Gaza Conflict (May 2021):

Nicholas Kristof is right when he mentions that Israel once allowed the rise of Hamas as a counterweight to the Palestine Liberation Organization. But Israel did much more than “allow.” In 1981, Brig. Gen. Yitzhak Segev, Israel’s military governor of Gaza, told me that he was giving money to the Muslim Brotherhood, the precursor of Hamas, on the instruction of the Israeli authorities. The funding was intended to tilt power away from both Communist and Palestinian nationalist movements in Gaza, which Israel considered more threatening than the fundamentalists.


In Profits of War: Inside the Secret U.S.-Israeli Arms Network, Ari Ben-Menashe, a former Israeli military intelligence operative, writes how Israeli intelligence funded "Palestinian Terrorists" (in) Chapter 8):

“The slush fund helped finance the intelligence community’s “black” operations around the world. These included funding Israeli-controlled “Palestinian terrorists” who would commit crimes in the name of the Palestinian revolution, but were actually pulling them off, usually unwittingly, as part of the Israeli propaganda machine.” (p. 120)


In The Other Side of Deception  former Mossad case officer Victor Ostrovsky writes :

“Supporting the radical elements of Muslim fundamentalism sat well with the Mossad’s general plan for the region. An Arab world run by fundamentalists would not be a party to any negotiations with the West, thus leaving Israel again as the only democratic, rational country in the region. And if the Mossad could arrange for the Hamas (Palestinian fundamentalists) to take over the Palestinian streets from the PLO, then the picture would be complete.” (p. 197)


United Press International reports in its article Israel gave major to aid to Hamas (Feb, 2001):

Israel and Hamas may currently be locked in deadly combat [the Second Intifada], but, according to several current and former U.S. intelligence officials, beginning in the late 1970s, Tel Aviv gave direct and indirect financial aid to Hamas over a period of years ... “The thinking on the part of some of the right-wing Israeli establishment was that Hamas and the other groups, if they gained control, would refuse to have anything to do with the pace process and would torpedo any agreements put in place,” said a U.S. government official. “Israel would still be the only democracy in the region for the United States to deal with,” he said.


PLO leader Yasser Arafat, has publicly said, multiple times in interviews that he knew Hamas was financed by Israel and he had proof of it:

Israeli Roots of Hamas Are Being Exposed: To the Italian daily L'Espresso, Arafat laid out the reasons for this support. "Hamas was constituted with the support of Israel. The aim was to create an organization antagonistic to the PLO. They received financing and training from Israel. They have continued to benefit from permits and authorizations, while we have been limited, even to build a tomato factory.
Rabin himself defined it as a fatal error. Some collaborationists of Israel are involved in these [terror] attacks," he said. "We have proof, and we are placing it at the disposal of the Italian government."
In an interview with the Dec. 11 Italian daily Corriere della Sera, Arafat said, "We are doing everything to stop the violence. But Hamas is a creature of Israel which at the time of Prime Minister [Yitzhak] Shamir [the late 1980s, when Hamas arose], gave them money and more than 700 institutions, among them schools, universities and mosques.
Even [former Israeli Prime Minister Yitzhak] Rabin ended up admitting it, when I charged him with it, in the presence of [Egpytian President Hosni] Mubarak."


In Chapter 8 - "Israel's Islamist", the book Devil's Game (by Robert Dreyfuss) quotes the former US ambassador to Saudi Arabia, Charles Freeman:

“Israel started Hamas,” says Charles Freeman, the veteran U.S. diplomat and former U.S. ambassador to Saudi Arabia. “It was a project of Shin Bet [the Israeli domestic intelligence agency], which had a feeling that they could use it to hem in the PLO.” (p. 191)


A US diplomatic memo (leaked on wikileaks) written by the US Ambassador to Israel quoted Israeli Defense Intelligence Chief, Amos Yadlin:

“Although not necessarily reflecting a GOI [government of Israel] consensus view, Yadlin said Israel would be “happy” if Hamas took over Gaza because the IDF could then deal with Gaza as a hostile state.”


A Wall Street Journal report How Israel Helped to Spawn Hamas (Jan 2009) quotes a Hamas member Mahmoud Musleh and retired Israeli official Avner Cohen to highlight the role of Israel in the rise of Hamas:

"Hamas, to my great regret, is Israel's creation," says Mr. Cohen, a Tunisian-born Jew who worked in Gaza for more than two decades ... Instead of trying to curb Gaza's Islamists from the outset, says Mr. Cohen, Israel for years tolerated and, in some cases, encouraged them as a counterweight to the secular nationalists of the Palestine Liberation Organization and its dominant faction, Yasser Arafat's Fatah. Israel cooperated with a crippled, half-blind cleric named Sheikh Ahmed Yassin, even as he was laying the foundations for what would become Hamas.
... A leader of Birzeit’s Islamist faction at the time was Mahmoud Musleh, now a pro-Hamas member of a Palestinian legislature elected in 2006. He recalls how usually aggressive Israeli security forces stood back and let conflagration develop. He denies any collusion between his own camp and the Israelis, but says “they hoped we would become an alternative to the PLO.”


In a TV interview with I24 News (2014), Avi Primor a former Israeli Ambassador to Germany and the EU said:

“It was the Israeli government, it was us who created Hamas, in order to create a counterweight to [Yasser Arafat’s] Fatah at the time. And we thought it would be a religious organization that would quarrel with Fatah, we couldn’t foresee what would become of it, but it’s our creation, these are the facts.”


Bezalel Smotrich, leader of Israel’s Religious Zionist Party and an Israeli Finance Minister explains in an interview to Knesset TV (in 2015) why Hamas is an "asset" to Israel:

“The [Palestinian Authority] is a burden and Hamas is an asset. On the same international field, in this game of delegitimization, and think about it for a moment, the [PA] is a burden and Hamas is an asset. It’s a terrorist organization. No one will recognize it. No one will give it status at the [International Criminal Court] ... Given that the main game, the central court, where we play now, is the international delegitimization, there [PA leader Abbas] is beating us in significant spaces. And Hamas, at this point and in my opinion, will be an asset. I don’t think I have to worry about [Hamas].”


In October 2023, Israeli newspaper Haaretz reported on March 2019 Likud party meeting in which Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu explained why it is necessary to fund Hamas:

“Anyone who wants to thwart the establishment of a Palestinian state has to support bolstering Hamas and transferring money to Hamas,” he told a meeting of his Likud party’s Knesset members in March 2019. “This is part of our strategy – to isolate the Palestinians in Gaza from the Palestinians in the West Bank.”


In Feb 2020, a Times of Israel article Liberman: Netanyahu sent Mossad head, general to Qatar, ‘begged’ it to pay Hamas highlighted:

Mossad chief Yossi Cohen and the top officer of the Israel Defense Forces in charge of Gaza, Herzi Halevi, visited Qatar earlier this month on the instructions of Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu to plead with its leaders to continue their periodical payments to Hamas, Yisrael Beytenu party chief Avigdor Liberman claimed Saturday night.
“Both Egypt and Qatar are angry with Hamas and planned to cut ties with them. Suddenly Netanyahu appears as the defender of Hamas, as though it was an environmental organization ... With Israel’s approval, Qatar since 2018 has periodically provided millions of dollars in cash to Hamas to pay for fuel for the Strip’s power plant, allow the group to pay its civil servants and provide aid to tens of thousands of impoverished families.


Former Israeli Foreign Minister Yossi Beilin, told German public broadcaster ZDF in an interview:

“It was Netanyahu who strengthened Hamas. Not supported, of course. But between the PLO and Hamas, he has always favored Hamas because they do not want a two-state solution. Hamas does not want a partition of the country, they want the the whole country. That’s why it was easier to deal with them than with the “National Movement”, which calls for a partition of the country and a two-state solution.”


It's also a text book political strategy of any right-wing religious fundamentalists group to create martyrs to use them for political violence. (Ofcourse, none of them are going to come out and publicly say that we did hope Hamas would terrorise and kill some Israeli citizens). But, actions speak loudly of their intention:

“In September 1993, the Rabin government signed the Oslo accords with the Palestine Liberation Organization (PLO). The accords, and the series of terror bombings [by Hamas] that followed their implementation, brought thousands of previously apolitical Israelis into the streets and onto the barricades in embittered protest. These neophyte activists poured into the pre-existing right-wing groups and placed themselves at the disposal of experienced organizers such as [Shin Bet informant] Avishai Raviv. One of these new activists was my son Yigal.”

The above excerpt is from a letter written to John F Kennedy Jr. by the mother of the assassin, Yigal Amir, who murdered Yitzhak Rabin, the Israeli Prime Minister who signed the Oslo Accords. As she highlights, terrorist attacks by Hamas provided a boost to the Israeli-Right, as it provided a fertile ground to radicalise even more Israelis to their violent ideology, and also to eliminate political opponents (like the former Israeli PM Yitzhak Rabin) in such an angry and politically charged environment.
Note: The event of nearly 21 years ago showed everyone in the Israeli establishment that Hamas had no hesitation in attacking Israelis. Despite this, Israel's current Prime Minister Netanyahu personally went out of his way to ensure Hamas was still well-funded. So the plan in funding Islamic terrorism amongst the Palestinians was not just to fight PLO, as they publicly claim, but to also ensure that attacks on Israelis kept happening (or, in other words, were even supported as state policy).

Update:
The killing of Hamas leader Ismail Haniyeh, and Hezbollah leader Hassan Nasrallah, also strongly indicates that the Israeli-Right still believe that it is important to not completely eliminate these groups. While Netanyahu's government is using the ignorance of the public (on counter-terrorism) to celebrate these assassination as some great victory for Israel's anti-terrorism operation, the reality is that the death of these leaders now mean that more hardline leaders will take control of the groups. This means both the groups will now choose to be even more violent with Israel, less trusting of them, while eschewing any options of diplomacy and political moderation.
In the article Tough-talking Haniyeh was seen as the more moderate face of Hamas Voice of America reported -

July 31, 2024: Ismail Haniyeh, the Hamas leader who was killed in Iran, was the tough-talking face of the Palestinian group's international diplomacy as war raged back in Gaza, where three of his sons were killed in an Israeli airstrike. But despite the rhetoric, he was seen by many diplomats as a moderate compared to the more hardline members of the Iran-backed group inside Gaza ... For all the tough language in public, Arab diplomats and officials had viewed him as relatively pragmatic compared with more hardline voices inside Gaza ...
Three of Haniyeh's sons ... were killed on April 10 when an Israeli air strike struck the car they were driving, Hamas said. Haniyeh also lost four of his grandchildren, three girls and a boy, in the attack, Hamas said. Haniyeh had ... said "the interests of the Palestinian people are placed ahead of everything" when asked if their killing would impact truce talks.
Haniyeh was an early advocate of Hamas entering politics. In 1994, he said that forming a political party "would enable Hamas to deal with emerging developments." Initially overruled by the Hamas leadership, it was later approved and Haniyeh became Palestinian prime minister after the group won Palestinian parliamentary elections in 2006 ...

Killing moderate leaders of the Palestinian resistance (or other Jihadi groups) is another important tactic used by the Israeli-Right to nurture Jihadi religious fundamentalists. The same tactic is apparent with their assassination of Hezbollah leader Hassan Nasrallah. A Newsweek article by an American veteran bluntly states that Nasrallah Assassination Will Only Make Israel Less Safe:

Oct 04, 2024: Many in the Middle East and America hailed the September 27 Israeli assassination of Hezbollah leader Hassan Nasrallah. Television stations in Israel had singing and dancing in their studios and some reporters handed out chocolate on the streets. In time, they may come to regret these celebrations.
Hassan Nasrallah was many things, but he was a cautious and pragmatic politician at heart. He used many inflammatory words in often-fiery speeches over the years, but kept his actions restrained. He held back many of the most violent and reckless voices within Hezbollah, seeking to thread the needle of keeping up resistance against Israeli strength while avoiding anything that might invite an Israeli military response.
... In a recent interview with Christiane Amanpour, Lebanese Foreign Minister Abdallah Habib claimed that in late September Nasrallah had agreed to a ceasefire with Benjamin Netanyahu. The Lebanese government claims it had confirmation from the U.S. and French governments that Netanyahu had agreed to the ceasefire — and then Nasrallah was assassinated anyway. Just days later, Israel invaded southern Lebanon.
Many in Israel apparently believed that if they took out the head of Hezbollah — along with a stunning number of other high-ranking Hezbollah leaders — the organization would be weakened or possibly even fall apart, improving Israel's security. Those hopes are unlikely to be realized. To the contrary, based on my experience fighting insurgent foes in both Iraq and Afghanistan, the more likely result will be an increase in the threat to Israel.
... As Americans observed in both Iraq and Afghanistan, any time you kill the leader of a militia or terror group, there is always someone else waiting in the wings. Such groups are expressly designed to survive the loss of a leader, even the top leader. Remember that al-Qaeda didn't disintegrate after Osama bin Laden's death, and when the terrorist Abu al-Zarqawi was killed in Iraq in 2006, his terror group eventually became the much more powerful ISIS.
Hezbollah is not going to be destroyed by the assassination of its leader, but now the group is likely to be more radical, more dangerous, and more lethal to Israel ... Israel may find Hezbollah much less willing to engage in diplomacy than before Nasrallah was killed ...

(And that's exactly what the religious fundamentalists in the Israeli-Right want - they need their fundamentalist counterpart in Palestine or other Arab states in order to politically survive and thrive in Israel.)

First, straight out, let me express strong doubts that Netanyahu would have chosen anywhere near the level of 10/7.  Or indeed much of the lower levels of violence that preceded it.
Many governments have, at times, benefited from opponents that can be painted as extremists or people that cannot be trusted.  A related notion is that of the "agent provocateur", someone tasked with making your opponent look bad.
I'll sit out any speculation as to whether Netanyahu would have welcomed even low levels of violence from Hamas.  I don't have any solid information, let alone evidence, to go on and would just go by my "feelings" and I suspect that is true for almost anyone who will try to argue either way.

Having said that, there is another angle than that of pitting PA/Fatah vs Hamas and that of examining non-violent resistance methods vs the use of violence.  Non-violence as perhaps best epitomized by Gandhi or ML King (note: this argument is pre-10/7 in nature *)
Non-violent resistance during the First Intifada
The First Intifada 1987-1993 (not at all to be confused with the Second) was a grassroots uprising, wrongly or correctly, perceived abroad at the time as presenting a unique challenge to Israel.  Being (relatively) non-violent, it risked presenting Israel as a one-sided oppressor and occupier.
Its stereotype, valid or invalid, is that of Palestinian teenagers throwing stones at tanks.  And Israel's response was not at all well-received by Western electorates.

In the first year in the Gaza Strip alone, 142 Palestinians were killed, while no Israelis died. 77 were shot dead, and 37 died from tear-gas inhalation. 17 died from beatings at the hand of Israeli police or soldiers.[59] During the whole six-year intifada, the Israeli army killed from 1,087 to 1,204 (or 1,284)[20][60][61] Palestinians, 241/332[61] being children. Tens of thousands were arrested (some sources said 57,000;[18][61] others said 120,000),[62] 481 were deported while 2,532 had their houses razed to the ground.[61] Between December 1987 and June 1991, 120,000 were injured, 15,000 arrested and 1,882 homes demolished.[63] One journalistic calculation reports that in the Gaza Strip alone from 1988 to 1993, some 60,706 Palestinians suffered injuries from shootings, beatings or tear gas.[64] In the first five weeks alone, 35 Palestinians were killed and some 1,200 wounded. Some regarded the Israeli response as encouraging more Palestinians into participating.[65] B'Tselem calculated 179 Israelis killed, while official Israeli statistics place the total at 200 over the same period. 3,100 Israelis, 1,700 of them soldiers, and 1,400 civilians suffered injuries

It was also a tough problem to solve for the IDF itself.  Ref. How Did the Intifada Affect the IDF? pub 1994

Contrary  to  the  dark  forecasts  of  several  early  analysts,  neither  Israel's  military apparatus nor (for that matter) Israeli society disintegrated as a result of the prolonged nature of the intifada. If anything, this form  of armed struggle -  like  others  before  it -  was  "routinized"  by  the  Israeli  polity,  and  thereby  rendered  tolerable.53  Even so, the intra-organizational problems to which the intifada gave rise  within the IDF do nevertheless warrant  specific  attention.  Because it posed unique strains, the conflict substantively modified the doctrines hitherto favored by Israel's armed forces, and affected  their structure and overall status within Israeli society.  The need to come to terms with these changes will doubtless occupy IDF attention for some time to come.

Israel may have either chosen to, out of its own volition, or been forced to, negotiate in good faith if Palestinian resistance had continued on that course.  It is also easy for people safely out of harm's way - like me - to argue that they should have.
Back to violence - Second Intifada
The Second Intifada, 2000-2005 and Hamas, since its Gaza takeover in 2007, have firmly avoided Israel being put in the dilemma presented to the UK in its final years in India.  That is the case whether or not Netanyahu had anything to do with.

B'Tselem reports that 1,053 Israelis were killed by Palestinian attacks through 30 April 2008


B'Tselem reports that through 30 April 2008, there were 4,745 Palestinians killed by Israeli security forces, and 44 Palestinians killed by Israeli civilians

Whether deliberate or not, the events at the start of Intifada Two may give the impression some Israeli politicians were not keen on keeping tempers down.  Alternatively, others blame the PA instead.
We don't know for sure who chose to promote what level of violence.  But we do know that violent and non-violent movements unfold in different ways and that the challenges to Israel are different in nature.  So are the stakes.
* 10/7 and beyond.
The level of atrocities committed by Hamas on 10/7, as well as the scale of casualties from IDF operations in Gaza since that date, means that it is hard to really apply my remarks above to the future.  (Nor indeed does it seem appropriate to answer the original in any form without strongly distinguishing between before and after 10/7)
On the one hand, internal Israeli sentiment while very critical against Netanyahu also (unsurprisingly) seems solidly against negotiations on items like the Two States option.
On the other hand, one can expect increasing pressure from the "Global South" against Israel, as well as a probable further drop of support amongst Western electorates (some of whom tend to confuse concern for Palestinian well-being with justification for Hamas' actions).

"some of whom tend to confuse concern for Palestinian well-being with justification for Hamas' actions" - I'll just say that there is a large portion that aren't confused, they just wont support Hamas, and as a by-product of Hamas enjoying plurality support by Palestinians, they also cannot support Palestinians without supporting Hamas.
